# Network Simulator in fedora - tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error: how to solve this error

Tags: fedora, software-installation

I'm trying to build and install `NS-allinone 2.34` on Fedora 23.  During the build process I'm getting the following error:

> tools/ranvar.cc: In member function ‘virtual double GammaRandomVariable::value()’:
>   tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error: cannot call constructor ‘GammaRandomVariable::GammaRandomVariable’ directly
>   tools/ranvar.cc:219:70: error: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::GammaRandomVariable’
>   make: *** [tools/ranvar.o] Error 1
>   Ns make failed!

What do I need to do to resolve this?

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Answer (score 1):

---

Simple : Your compiler g++-5.* is way too new to compile the old ns-2.34 code.
`# dnf install compat-gcc-34-c++`

Solution 1) `$ cd ns-allinone-2.34/ && export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./install`

---

Solution 2) `$ cd ns-allinone-2.34/ && patch -p0 < ns234_gcc49.patch && ./install` Link, the patch : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZDNyV1BPZHhEY0U/view?usp=sharing
( Not sure this one (2) is tested with Fedora 23.)

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)